# How can I run this Django Server with gunicorn?

Tags: python, django, gunicorn, wsgi

I'm trying to run my Django app with the Gunicorn web server. But I'm having difficulty doing so.

My directory structure looks like this:

```
$ pwd
/Users/my_user/my_django_project

$ ls -R
./MySite:
__init__.py         migration_settings.py   urls.py
local_settings.py   settings.py             wsgi.py

./app1:
<blah> <blah> <blah>

./app2:
<blah> <blah> <blah>

./app3:
<blah> <blah> <blah>
```

This is how I run the Django test server, it works:

```
$ ./manage.py runserver --settings=MySite.local_settings 0.0.0.0:8000
```

How do I run the same server with gunicorn instead of `./manage.py`? Everything I have seen indicates I should do the following. But as you can see, it gives me an error:

```
$ pwd
/Users/my_user/my_django_project

$ gunicorn -v
gunicorn (version 19.7.1)

$ DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=MySite.local_settings gunicorn MySite.wsgi:application --log-file=-

[2018-02-21 19:26:01 -0500] [9038] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
[2018-02-21 19:26:01 -0500] [9038] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (9038)
[2018-02-21 19:26:01 -0500] [9038] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2018-02-21 19:26:01 -0500] [9041] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9041
[2018-02-21 19:26:01 -0500] [9041] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 578, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 126, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 135, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 352, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/Users/my_user/my_django_project/MySite/wsgi.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
ImportError: No module named django.core.wsgi
[2018-02-21 19:26:01 -0500] [9041] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9041)
[2018-02-21 19:26:01 -0500] [9038] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2018-02-21 19:26:01 -0500] [9038] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

Why is it complaining about `django.core.wsgi` not being found? As you can see, I'm finding it when I run this from the shell prompt interactively:

```
$ pip install django
Requirement already satisfied: django in /Users/my_user/my_virtual_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages


$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Feb  7 2017, 00:08:15)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import django
>>> import django.core
>>> import django.core.wsgi
>>> from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
>>>
```

What am I doing wrong here and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried installing gunicorn in the virtual environment?

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately that didn't change the error.

Comment: `gunicorn hello.wsgi:application --bind example.com:8001` read this blog http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/ I followed this guy always